# how to trigger google onSignIn data-onsuccess without global onSignIn function?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, google-signin

After playing around with google sign https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in.  I wanted to clean up the code a bit by placing it in another file and maybe renaming them.

But somehow `data-onsuccess` would not work if I put the `onSignIn` function as an object's attribute.

I have something like this to give it a try

```
const google_auth = {};
google_auth.id_token = null;

google_auth.onSignIn = (googleUser) => {
    const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    const id_token = google_auth.id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

    console.log(profile, 'profile');
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('ID token: ' + id_token);
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    console.log(id_token.split('.'), 'id_token split');
};
```

then for html I tried

`<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="google_auth.onSignIn"></div>`

the function will not be called though.  If I just use the original code such as

```
const google_auth = {};
google_auth.id_token = null;

function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    const profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    const id_token = google_auth.id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

    console.log(profile, 'profile');
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('ID token: ' + id_token);
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    console.log(id_token.split('.'), 'id_token split');
};
```

`<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>`

Which works perfectly, I tried googling about `data-onsuccess` attributes but no one really talk much about this situation.  Most people saying it doesn't work with the framework.

Thanks in advance for any help / suggestions.

Comment: were you able to find the solution?